# Yellow chevron markings at end of runway, what do they mean?

Tags: landing, runways, airport-markings

In [this YouTube video (link starts video at time of interest)](https://youtu.be/6f8v5azVmp8?t=614), the pilot appears to land in the area marked by the large yellow chevrons, in what appears to me (a layperson) to be a taxi way.

[image: Screenshot of markings in question]

What are the meaning of the yellow markings? Under what conditions can a landing be made before this point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are not chevrons but arrowheads used to mark the start of the runway. So, yes, he did land on the taxiway.

[image]

<sup>Source: [FAA Airfield Standards Quick Reference](https://www.faa.gov/airports/southern/airport_safety/part139_cert/media/aso-airfield-standards-quick-reference.pdf)</sup>

He does land slightly before the runway threshold. He even says he is going to land short. Since there was nothing on the taxiway leading to the runway then it seems there is no problem doing that.

[image]

<sup>screenshot from Google maps of KYKM runway 22 threshold</sup>

For comparison, chevrons mark either stopways or blast pads and look like this:
[image]

<sup>same source as first image</sup>

They may include an [EMAS bed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineered_materials_arrestor_system), so touching down there would not be a good idea.

Comment: Are there markings meaning "absolutely no landing here" for some extension at the end of a runway?

Comment: I would say that it's not a good idea to land on chevrons, which are a little different from the arrowheads. Chevrons can be on an EMAS bed. You don't want to touch down there as it can damage the EMAS and likely the plane. Chevrons look like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=runway+chevrons&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMyLu2pKDUAhUL2oMKHUa6A8MQ_AUICSgB&biw=1024&bih=664#imgrc=-LIGEwqeSrW_iM:)

Comment: This is a good answer, the pilot in the video showed poor judgment landing there, and then posting it for the whole world to see.

Comment: Don't displaced thresholds usually mean that the bearing capacity of the surface with arrows is not high enough to withstand landings from at least some of the planes that land there?

Comment: @BaileyS It can mean that. Displaced thresholds can be used for numerous reasons. Sometimes it is for a blast pad, which is not intended for landing. Sometimes it's there to allow a stopway for the opposite runway which may or may not include an EMAS bed. It can be temporary, for construction. There are regulations as to the heights and distances of obstacles from the end of the runway. If you look at [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27976/8730) it appears the runway was a bit too close to the road. It doesn't *necessarily* mean it won't hold the weight.

Comment: Edited the answer a little. After reading Donna Speidel's answer I watched the video again and the arrowheads are clearly yellow. They looked white in the satellite photo. So it's not a displaced threshold, but markings to indicate where the taxiway ends and the runway begins.

Answer (score 0):

Yellow arrowheads before the threshold bar mean you shouldn't land or take off in that area.  White arrowheads mean you can roll out from that area, just not land.  The displaced threshold is usually there due to obstructions or construction.