# How far from a taxiway, can a walking or biking trail be built?

Tags: taxiing, airport-design, airport

How far from a small single runway airport's taxiway, can something like a walking or biking trail be built?

Comment: Depends on the size of the aircraft the airport handles, and if the airport perimeter is fenced off or not.

Comment: For one instance, there is (or was a few years ago) a nice trail from the parking area of the Alpine County (California) airport down to the Carson River.  I dare say you'll find quite a few other instance if you fly into e.g. the Idaho or Montana back country.

Comment: Very close.  GoogleEarth Kearney, AZ's airport.  The ramp has golf course access.

Comment: The taxiway can be a trail.

Comment: seeing that in places like Gibraltar major roads cross taxiways, very close indeed :)

Comment: There are airfields where paths cross the runway.

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27976/62), but US-specific

Answer (score 2):

ICAO recommends somewhere between 16.25 and 57.50 metres from the centreline, depending on the type of aircraft that use the taxiway (code letter A-F).

From ICAO Annex 14:

> 3.9.8    **Recommendation.**— *The separation distance between the centre line of a taxiway and the centre line of a runway, the centre line of a parallel taxiway or an object should not be less than the appropriate dimension specified in Table 3-1, except that it may be permissible to operate with lower separation distances at an existing aerodrome if an aeronautical study indicates that such lower separation distances would not adversely affect the safety or significantly affect the regularity of operations of aeroplanes.*

...

> 3.11.1    A taxiway, other than an aircraft stand taxilane, shall be included in a strip.
>
> 3.11.2    **Recommendation.**— *A taxiway strip should extend symmetrically on each side of the centre line of the taxiway throughout the length of the taxiway to at least the distance from the centre line given in Table 3-1, column 11.*

[image]

Comment: Also, there are plenty of small GA airports (in the US - I'm not that familiar with other countries) that don't have taxiways.

Comment: @jamesqf Sure, but that's not within the scope of this question

Comment: @J. Hougaard: Perfectly within scope, as it demonstrates that there's no need for an airport to have a taxiway, and nothing (in the US, anyway) to prohibit trails beside, on, or across those that do.